# How can I change the background image view transparency image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

It is the code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor= [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
```

My "yourimage.png" have some space that is transparency. But it shows me it becomes black. How can I change it to show the transparency instead of black color? thz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `opaque` property on the view to `NO`.